# How do I monitor internet data usage for a specific network?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, android, bandwidth

So here's my problem.  I am using a wifi hotspot from Airtel (in India) that provides internet connectivity via a SIM card on their 4G network.

The data goes to 0 way too quickly (in my opinion) and they will not provide me with any backup other than "the charges are proper per your usage".  Because I connect to that one hotspot with my cell phone and laptop, I know I need to manually track and add the data usage.

However, what makes the calculation difficult (if not impossible) is that I will use different networks to access the internet. For example, at times, I am connecting my laptop to the home wifi network, other times at Starbucks, and other times on the Airtel Hotspot.

So I need a bandwidth/data tracker that can keep track of the data usage per network. Is there something out there that runs on Mac OSX and Android?

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the app for android called 'My Data Manager' a try? It tracks all data usage on data, wifi, and roaming. You can find this app on the play store and it is free.

As for monitoring your wireless usage on your Mac I would give Bandwidth+ a try. You should be able to find it on the AppStore on your Mac.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bandwidth+/id490461369?mt=12 - Bandwidth+

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en - My Data Manager

Comment: Thanks,Daniel!  I currently use "My Data Manager" on my S5, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to offer the ability to track data usage from different networks, only a total.  I did download Bandwith+ for my macbook and that does Exactly what I need!  Now if I can only find equivalent apps for my ipad and phone that will let me track data per network. . .  But a big "Thank you" for helping me.  :)